# How to map `g CTRL-G` command in visual mode in Vim?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, vi

I really like this command as it shows me number of selected lines, words, characters & bytes.
http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#v_g_CTRL-G

But somehow I can't get the mapping to work:

I tried:

```
vnoremap <leader>z g<C-g>
vmap <leader>z g<C-g>
```

Answer (score 4):

When I tried it, I was like "wow, it really doesn't work". Then I realized that the status message was showed and disappeared just too quickly. So for your mapping "to work" you can show the last status message using variable [`v:statusmsg`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#v%3Astatusmsg)

```
vnoremap <leader>z g<C-g>:<C-U>echo v:statusmsg<CR>
```

but that leaves you in normal mode. You can reselect the area again by <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> (it wouldn't do to add it in mapping, it would redraw the status message with `-- VISUAL --`). If you know about some method how to keep message displayed (ie. without the need to display it again with `echo v:statusmsg`), then you don't need this not very useful workaround (as it is it seems better to use <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>CTRL+g</kbd> combination instead of mapping to me).

---

Edit: I found interesting function [`sleep`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#gs) (or [`gs`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#gs), like *go sleep*).

```
vnoremap <leader>z g<C-g>2gs
```

Now you can see the message. You are not able to do anything for two seconds but it can be interrupted with `CTRL-C` or `CTRL-Break` on MS-DOS. (Obviously, you can define different time period.)

Comment: Thanks @ryuichiro . This one works. I don't mind that it disappears after a while. Will try to find a way to stay in visual way.

Answer (score 2):

Another way that seems to work (at least in gVim):

```
vnoremap <leader>z :call feedkeys("gvg\<C-G>")<CR>
```

The idea here is that the characters specified in the `feedkeys()` call are "injected" *after* the call is executed (i.e. after `<CR>` is run by the `<leader>z` mapping). Hence the need to reselect the visual area using `gv`.